# how to create columns in a dataframe with the values of another

Tags: r

I have this df with 3 columns

```
 > df
ProyectoID                         Nombre Contratado
1    D0000052 D.O.Línea Alta Velocidad Vitor 3606443.81
2    X0000100 AT Conservación Red Foral Bizk 2218057.00
3    D0000062 D.O. Alta velocidad Hernialde- 1545665.21
4    CABL2016 Proyectos y D.O. de Abastecimi 1160413.00
5    X0000120 Bloque proyectos y obras STI 2 1063783.11
```

and df2 with only one column:

```
   > df2
    Años
    1  2007
    2  2008
    3  2009
    4  2010
```

I want to add a new column to df for each value of df2 so inside this loop

```
for (variable in df2) {
 .....
}
```

I'm trying several options but not works

```
df$variable=0
```

or

```
df <- df %>% mutate(variable=0)
```

this creates me, that is, it creates the new column with the name "variable" not the value

```
df
ProyectoID                         Nombre Contratado variable
1    D0000052 D.O.Línea Alta Velocidad Vitor 3606443.81        0
2    X0000100 AT Conservación Red Foral Bizk 2218057.00        0
3    D0000062 D.O. Alta velocidad Hernialde- 1545665.21        0
4    CABL2016 Proyectos y D.O. de Abastecimi 1160413.00        0
```

I tried this but with error

```
for (indice in 1:nrow(df2)) {
 df$df2[indice,]=0
 df<-df%>%mutate(df2[indice,]=0)
 df<-df%>%mutate(as.character(df2[indice,])=0)
}
```

Any idea, please?

I need something like this

```
ProyectoID                         Nombre Contratado 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 
1    D0000052 D.O.Línea Alta Velocidad Vitor 3606443.81    0    0    0    0    
2    X0000100 AT Conservación Red Foral Bizk 2218057.00    0    0    0    0
```

regards

Comment: Not clear. How is df2 connected with df? What are those dates in df2? Please explain what you are trying to achieve and  share the expected output

Comment: df2 is not connected with df df2 contains a series of years and I need add in df a new column for each year in df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `df2$Años` to character and assign multiple columns to 0.

```
df[as.character(df2$Años)] <- 0

#  ProyectoID                         Nombre Contratado 2007 2008 2009 2010
#1   D0000052 D.O.Línea Alta Velocidad Vitor    3606444    0    0    0    0
#2   X0000100 AT Conservación Red Foral Bizk    2218057    0    0    0    0
#3   D0000062 D.O. Alta velocidad Hernialde-    1545665    0    0    0    0
#4   CABL2016 Proyectos y D.O. de Abastecimi    1160413    0    0    0    0
#5   X0000120 Bloque proyectos y obras STI 2    1063783    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Is

```
df$Años <- df2$Años
```

what you are looking for? This assumes that the rows of `df` and `df2` are rowwise connected to each other semantically.

Answer (score 0):

assign the year in loop like this.

```
for (anos in as.character(df2$anos)) {
  df[[anos]] = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(as.character(df2$Años)), ~ 0 * .)
```